# How to get percentage from data collected in ChartJS?

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I'm having trouble with percentages.

Here's the data from my database:
**Jobstreet** - **2** (total number of users who pick this as source of job application)
**Facebook** - **1** (total number of users who pick this as source of job application)
**Indeed.com** - **1** (total number of users who pick this as source of job application)

[image: myGraph]
*The code I have seems to just append the percentage sign.*

Now, I'm expecting to get something like this:
*Jobstreet - 50% | Facebook - 25% | Indeed.com - 25%*

And if you sum them up, you'll get 100%.

I don't know how to get that. Please help me with my problem.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/public/ajax/generateChart/",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            var source = [];
            var count = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                source.push(data[i].source);
                count.push(data[i].number);
            }

            var config = {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        data: count,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255,1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ]
                    }],
                    labels: source
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
                    },
                    animation: {
                        animateScale: true,
                        animateRotate: true
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                                var total = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
                                    return previousValue + currentValue;
                                });
                                var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                                var precentage = Math.floor(((currentValue/total) * 100)+0.5);
                                return ": " + precentage + "%";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var ctx = $('#chartCanvas');
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that using the following tooltips label callback function and a chart plugin ...

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
         var _data = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
         var data = /\./.test(_data) ? _data.toFixed(2) : _data;
         return label + ' - ' + data + '%';
      }
   }
}
```

<sub>**ᴄʜᴀʀᴛ ᴘʟᴜɢɪɴ**</sub>

```
plugins: [{
   beforeInit: function(c) {
      var data = c.data.datasets[0].data
      var data_sum = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      var each_one = 100 / data_sum;
      c.data.datasets[0].data = data.map(e => e * each_one);
   }
}]
```

<sup>add the plugin followed by your chart options</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://istack.000webhostapp.com/json/t5.json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         var source = [];
         var count = [];

         for (var i in data) {
            source.push(data[i].source);
            count.push(+data[i].number);
         }

         var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
               datasets: [{
                  data: count,
                  backgroundColor: [
                     'rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)',
                     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                     'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                     'rgba(153, 102, 255,1)',
                     'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                  ]
               }],
               labels: source
            },
            options: {
               responsive: false,
               legend: {
                  position: 'bottom',
               },
               title: {
                  display: false,
                  text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
               },
               animation: {
                  animateScale: true,
                  animateRotate: true
               },
               tooltips: {
                  callbacks: {
                     label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        var _data = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var data = /\./.test(_data) ? _data.toFixed(2) : _data;
                        return label + ' - ' + data + '%';
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            plugins: [{
               beforeInit: function(c) {
                  var data = c.data.datasets[0].data
                  var data_sum = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                  var each_one = 100 / data_sum;
                  c.data.datasets[0].data = data.map(e => e * each_one);
               }
            }]
         }
         var ctx = $('#chartCanvas');
         window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
      },
      error: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartCanvas" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for.  You just append the percentage sign in the tooltip. What I'm trying to say is that my data is the number of how many user use this platform as they job search engine. It will count base on how many. And I should see in the chart is the percentage of 3 parts. (For example: Facebook have 1, Indeed have 1 and Jobstreet have 2, so the result should be FB = 25%, Indeed = 25% and Jobstreet = 50%. By the way thanks for the effort showing us some example.

Comment: Just tested my SQL command, return this JSON data:  
`[{"source":"Facebook","0":"Facebook","number":"1","1":"1"},{"source":"Indeed.com","0":"Indeed.com","number":"1","1":"1"},{"source":"Jobstreet","0":"Jobstreet","number":"2","1":"2"}]`  

Can you try this one? If you want to know my SQL command, I can share it with you.

Comment: By the way `[number]` is the total count of the source, same with the `[1]`

Comment: ah, my bad. haven't properly read your question earlier. seems I better go sleep now `:/`. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://istack.000webhostapp.com/json/t5.json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         var source = [];
         var count = [];

         for (var i in data) {
            source.push(data[i].source);
            count.push(+data[i].number);
         }

         var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
               datasets: [{
                  data: count,
                  backgroundColor: [
                     'rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)',
                     'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                     'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                     'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                     'rgba(153, 102, 255,1)',
                     'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                  ]
               }],
               labels: source
            },
            options: {
               responsive: false,
               legend: {
                  position: 'bottom',
               },
               title: {
                  display: false,
                  text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
               },
               animation: {
                  animateScale: true,
                  animateRotate: true
               },
               tooltips: {
                  callbacks: {
                     label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        var _data = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var data = /\./.test(_data) ? _data.toFixed(2) : _data;
                        return label + ' - ' + data + '%';
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            plugins: [{
               beforeInit: function(c) {
                  var data = c.data.datasets[0].data
                  var data_sum = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                  var each_one = 100 / data_sum;
                  c.data.datasets[0].data = data.map(e => e * each_one);
               }
            }]
         }
         var ctx = $('#chartCanvas');
         window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
      },
      error: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartCanvas" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: sir, how do you show both the percentage and the actual amount?

Comment: Add some explanation, please!